# Loop triggered by Tkinter button and ended by another

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

The following code will show a small Tkinter user interface, however my buttons will not trigger the loop called copy_loop.  I have been trying for several hours and I cannot figure out how to fix this.  Any help will be very appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.isrunning = False

        self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='start')
        self.button1.bind = ("<Button-1>", self.startrunning)
        self.button1.pack()

        self.button2 = tk.Button(main, text='stop')
        self.button2.bind = ("<Button-1>", self.stoprunning)
        self.button2.pack()

    def startrunning(self, event):
        self.isrunning = True
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.copy_loop)
        t.start()

    def stoprunning(self, event):
        self.isrunning = False

    def copy_loop(self):
        while self.isrunning:
            print("Running...")

main = tk.Tk()
app = App(main)
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` is a function, not an attribute.  Where you have:

```
self.button1.bind = ("<Button-1>", self.startrunning)
```

you are actually *overwriting* the `bind` function on your instance. It is now a tuple.

Instead, do:

```
self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.startrunning)
```

And likewise for `button2`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an equals sign where there shouldn't be one. The command should be:

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='start')
self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.startrunning)
```

Or the much neater:

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='start', command=self.startrunning)
```

And your method signatures should have `event=None`:

```
def startrunning(self, event=None):
```

Or even more flexible:

```
def startrunning(self, *args):
```